# Shutdown: CLI vs GUI

Tags: shutdown

Is there a difference between doing a shutdown via Ubuntu's GUI versus doing a "sudo shutdown now" from the terminal? I ask this as I notice that my machines take longer to shutdown if I shutdown via the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `sudo shutdown -h now`?

Anyways, as long as you use this ^^^ command, there should be no difference.

It probably takes longer to shut down from GUI since it has to kill the X server and such, whilst if shutting down from CLI they are already dead.

Comment: According to the manpage, `-h` is equivalent to `--poweroff`, which is the default anyway.   It's also likely that the OP is running from within the desktop environment, so X will still be running.